# Элементы справа изображения - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Сделал следующую конструкцию:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-8 thumb cursor">
        <a class="thumbnail cursor" href="#">
            <img style = "position:left; margin-right:50%;" class = "imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg"/>
            <div class="wrapper cursor">
                <div class="caption post-content cursor">
                    <p class = "aria">Text1</p>
                    <p class = "fontd">Text2</p>
                    <button class = "buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Нужно, чтобы кнопка (под классом buttonx, который отвечает только за стилистику кнопки) и два текста (классы тоже отвечают только за стили), которые находятся выше кнопки перенести правее изображения. Вот скриншот, красный цвет - изображение, которое должно быть левее этих трех элементов, а не ниже.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Если ты пишешь на бутстрапе, ну так и загони свои элементы в сетку:

```
<div class="row">
   <!-- левая колонка с картинкой -->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class = "imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg"/>
   </div>
   <!-- правая колонка с текстом и кнопкой -->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper cursor">
            <div class="caption post-content cursor">
                <p class = "aria">Lady in Red</p>
                <p class = "fontd">Туалетная вода</p>
                <button class = "buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>        
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Однако, проблема теперь новая. row растянул все по ширине экрана, а нужно чтобы горизонтально поместилось 3 таких.

Comment: @georgeviskin, ну так и помести этот row внутрь col-md-4. А вообще почитай про сетку бутстрап, раз уж ты используешь этот фреймворк: https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/22-the-grid-system-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

Задайте изображению `float:left;` - это будет обтекание этой картинки, т.е. если текст будут по высоте больше картинки, то всё, что ниже картинки - будет уже на всю строчку.